# Evaluate $ \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{x\ln(1-\sin x)}{\sin x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Solve the following integral
$$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{x\ln \left( 1-\sin x \right)}{\sin x}dx}
\\
I\left( a \right) =\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{x\ln \left( 1-a\sin x \right)}{\sin x}}dx\quad \implies  \quad I'\left( a \right) =-\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{x}{\left( 1-a\sin x \right)}}dx$$

$$ \quad $$
$$
\int{\frac{1}{\left( 1-a\sin x \right)}dx}=\int{\frac{1}{\sin ^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos ^2\frac{x}{2}+a\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}}dx}
\\
=\int{\frac{1}{\sin ^2\frac{x}{2}+\cos ^2\frac{x}{2}+a\text{2}\sin \frac{x}{2}\cos \frac{x}{2}}dx}=2\int{\frac{d\left( \tan \frac{x}{2} \right)}{\left( a+\tan \frac{x}{2} \right) ^2+\left( \sqrt{1-a^2} \right) ^2}}$$

$$
\\
=2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\arctan \frac{a+\tan \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}
\\
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{x}{\left( 1-a\sin x \right)}}dx=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{xd\left( 2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\arctan \frac{a+\tan \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} \right)}$$=
 $$
2\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\arctan \frac{a+\tan \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}x\Bigg\vert_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}-\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\arctan \frac{a+\tan \frac{x}{2}}{\sqrt{1-a^2}}dx}$$
\

Comment: lol @lulu so cryptic

Comment: I've tried to clean up the formatting.  Check to ensure that I didn't change your meaning.

Comment: Does this answer your question [after the substitution $\tan(x/2)\to x$, as mentioned here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3490404  ]? [Proving that $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)dx=\frac{\pi^3}{16}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3050696/proving-that-int-01-frac-arctan-xx-ln-left-frac1x21-x2-rightd)