# The calculation of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^4}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, harmonic-numbers

**Happy New Year 2020, Romania**

In this recent post, [Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{\arctan x\ln^2 x}{1+x^2}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3492573/evaluate-int-01-frac-arctan-x-ln2-x1x2-dx/3492831#3492831), the proposed integral reduces to the calculation of $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^3}$ which is known in the literature. Now, what can we say about the more advanced version of it, the one with $n^4$ in the denominator?

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^4}$$

Can we do it by series manipulations? It looks like a new series in the literature.

**A good note**: With the previous result in hand which we combine with some of the **Cornel**'s work, we immediately arrive at two delightful series results,

> $$i) \ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{n^3}=\frac{61 }{192}\pi ^2 \zeta (3)+\frac{1973 }{128}\zeta (5)+\frac{\pi ^5}{16}-\frac{1}{128} \pi  \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);$$
> $$ii) \ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_{2 n}^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^3 G}{8}+\frac{1}{64}\pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{2997 }{256}\zeta (5)-\frac{\pi ^5}{32}+\frac{1}{256} \pi  \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right).$$

How would you go proving these last two results?

**Another good note**: Remaining on the ground with alternating harmonic series of weight $5$ and harmonic numbers of the type $H_{2n}$, we might be curious to know what the value of the series $\displaystyle \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_{2 n}^{(4)}}{n}$ is.

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}^{(4)}}{n}$$
> $$=4\zeta(5)-\frac{3}{128}\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{7}{128}\log(2)\zeta(4)+\frac{\pi^5}{192}-\frac{\pi^3}{16}G-\frac{\pi}{1536}\psi^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right).$$

This last series is elegantly calculated in [A simple strategy of calculating two alternating harmonic series generalizations](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333339284_A_simple_strategy_of_calculating_two_alternating_harmonic_series_generalizations) where one may also find its generalization with respect to the order of the harmonic number.

Comment: Nice and (+1) for the question.

Comment: so the integral representation for your sum is $\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx$ which can be converted to $\int_0^\infty \frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx$ which I think is manageable.

Comment: @AliShather Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

A solution in large steps by **Cornel I. Valean** to the main series

> The value of the series is 
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1}\frac{H_{2n}}{n^4}=\frac{\pi }{192}  \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{\pi ^2}{3} \zeta (3)-\frac{437}{64} \zeta (5)-\frac{\pi ^5}{24}, \tag1$$
>   where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$th harmonic number, $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function, and $\psi^{(n)}$ denotes the Polygamma function.

We will make use of a powerful result with harmonic numbers which is presented in the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**,
$$\int_0^{\infty } \tanh (\pi x)\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{x}{n^2+x^2}\right) \textrm{d}x=2 H_{2n}-H_n,$$
and that is proved in two ways in the mentioned book on pages $200$ - $203$.

Replacing $n$ by $2n$ in the identity above, multiplying both sides by $1/n^4$, taking the sum from $n=1$ to $\infty$, and rearranging the resulting series, we get

$$120 \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{H_n}{n^4}-120\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_n}{n^4}-16\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{  H_{2 n}}{n^4}$$
$$=\frac{2}{3}\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\tanh (\pi  x)}{x^5} \left(\pi ^2 x^2-6 \pi  x \coth \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)+12\right) \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{36}\int _0^{\infty }\left(\int _0^{\infty }\tanh (\pi  x) \left(\pi ^2 x^2-6 \pi  x \coth \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)+12\right)y^4 e^{-xy} \textrm{d}y\right)\textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{1}{36}\int _0^{\infty }\left(\int _0^{\infty }\tanh (\pi  x) \left(\pi ^2 x^2-6 \pi  x \coth \left(\frac{\pi  x}{2}\right)+12\right)y^4 e^{-xy} \textrm{d}
x\right)\textrm{d}y$$
$$\small=\int_0^{\infty } \biggr(\frac{y^4 }{6 \pi }\psi \left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{y}{\pi }+2\right)\right)-\frac{y^4 }{6 \pi }\psi\left(\frac{y}{4 \pi }\right)+\frac{y^4}{48 \pi } \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{y}{\pi }+3\right)\right)-\frac{y^4}{48 \pi } \psi ^{(1)}\left(\frac{y+\pi }{4 \pi }\right)
$$
$$
+\frac{y^4 }{1152 \pi }\psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{y}{\pi }+2\right)\right)-\frac{y^4}{1152 \pi } \psi ^{(2)}\left(\frac{y}{4 \pi }\right)-\frac{y^3}{3}-\frac{\pi  y^2}{6}-\frac{\pi ^2 y}{18}\biggr) \textrm{d}y$$
$$=248 \zeta (5)-\frac{14}{3} \pi ^2 \zeta (3)+\frac{2 }{3}\pi ^5-\frac{1}{12} \pi  \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right),$$

where for avoiding some tedious calculations I used *Mathematica* (but these can also be done perfectly manually). For example, the last integral has a nonelementary antiderivative in terms of Polygamma and Negapolygamma functions (that is, for the latter the order becomes negative).

Since we know the classical results,

> $$\small 2\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{H_k}{k^m}=(m+2)\zeta(m+1)-\sum_{k=1}^{m-2} \zeta(m-k) \zeta(k+1), m\ge2;$$
>   $$\small \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1}\frac{H_k}{k^{2m}}=\left(m+\frac{1}{2}\right)\eta(2m+1)-\frac{1}{2}\zeta(2m+1)-\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\eta(2i)\zeta(2m-2i+1), m\ge1$$
>   where $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}$ is the $n$th harmonic number, $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function, and $\eta$ represents the Dirichlet eta function,

then the stated result follows.

**First note:** Be careful *Mathematica* goes crazy during the calculations and you might think something is wrong, but it's not. All the calculations should be done very carefully.

**Second note:** Essentially, this strategy opens the gates to evaluate very advanced harmonic series like

> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(H_{kn}^{(m)})^r}{n^p}, \ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{(n-1)}\frac{(H_{kn}^{(m)})^r}{n^p}.$$

**Third note:** To make everything easier in the work with Negapolygamma it's important to groups everything strategically. I'll give an example.

> Let's prove that 
>   $$\psi ^{(-2)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi ^{(-2)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)=\frac{1}{4}\left(\log(2\pi)-\frac{2}{\pi}G\right).$$

**Proof.** Let's denote $I=\psi ^{(-2)}\left(\frac{3}{4}\right)-\psi ^{(-2)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)= \int_{1/4}^{3/4} \log (\Gamma (x)) \textrm{d}x$.

If we let the variable change $x\mapsto 1-x$ in the last integral, we get $\displaystyle I=\int_{1/4}^{3/4} \log\left(\Gamma (1-x)\right) \textrm{d}x$, that if we add to the initial integral and then combine with the Euler's reflection formula for Gamma function and the Fourier series of $\log(\sin(x))$, we get 
\begin{equation*}
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1/4}^{3/4} \log\left(\Gamma(x)\Gamma (1-x)\right) \textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\int_{1/4}^{3/4} \log\left(\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}\right) \textrm{d}x
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
=\frac{1}{4}\log(\pi)-\frac{1}{2}\int_{1/4}^{3/4} \log\left(\sin(\pi x)\right) \textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{4}\left(\log(2\pi)-\frac{2}{\pi}G\right).
\end{equation*}

When taken separately we'll also have to deal with the derivative of the Riemann zeta function, and it is not hard to see the presence of the **Glaisher–Kinkelin constant** in every of the two Negapolygamma particular values like here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolyGamma%5B-2%2C+1%2F4%5D. So, you want to better group everything strategically.

---

A solution in large steps by **Cornel** to the supplementary series

> $$i) \ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{n^3}=\frac{61 }{192}\pi ^2 \zeta (3)+\frac{1973 }{128}\zeta (5)+\frac{\pi ^5}{16}-\frac{1}{128} \pi  \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right);$$
>   $$ii) \ \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_{2 n}^{(3)}}{n^2}=\frac{\pi ^3 G}{8}+\frac{1}{64}\pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{2997 }{256}\zeta (5)-\frac{\pi ^5}{32}+\frac{1}{256} \pi  \psi ^{(3)}\left(\frac{1}{4}\right).$$

With the right results in hands, the extraction will happen very fast. So, here is what we need:

$a)$ The series result in $(1)$

$b)$ The Cauchy product of two series, 
$$\operatorname{Li}_2(x)\operatorname{Li}_3(x)=6\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\frac{H_n}{n^4}+3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\frac{H_n^{(2)}}{n^3}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} x^n\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n^2}-10\operatorname{Li}_5(x).$$

$c)$ The special integral

$$\int_0^1 \frac{\log(1-x) \log ^2(x) \log(1+x^2)}{x} \textrm{d}x$$
$$=\frac{7}{48} \pi ^2 \zeta (3)-\frac{1}{4} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}}{n^4}-\frac{1}{2} \sum _{n=1}^{\infty }(-1)^{n-1} \frac{ H_{2 n}^{(2)}}{n^3}-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } (-1)^{n-1}\frac{ H_{2 n}^{(3)}}{n^2},$$

which is calculated in the preprint [The derivation of eighteen special challenging logarithmic integrals by Cornel Ioan Valean](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334598773_The_derivation_of_eighteen_special_challenging_logarithmic_integrals).

**Done.**

Comment: beautiful (+1).

Answer (score 4):

Lets start with the integral representation of the sum,
$$I=\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx-\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx}_{\large1/x\ \mapsto x}$$

$$=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx+\int_0^1\frac{(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x)\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx$$

$$\Longrightarrow 2I=\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx+\frac{\pi}2\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx}_{-6\beta(4)}$$

$$I=\frac12\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx-\frac{3\pi}{2}\beta(4)$$

where [$\beta(4)=\frac{\psi_3(1/4)}{768}-\frac{\pi^4}{96}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function?fbclid=IwAR2JKUjyn8sG4wMdUfeT3JyJLpw7C-aanbnwRYbIZ0k9QYwA3Hz1_0OsQhU) is the Dirichlet beta function.

---

To complete my solution, I am going to borrow @user97357329's result in the comment below,

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{ \arctan x\ln ^3x}{1+x^2} \ dx=\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\left(2 \ln ^2x+\pi ^2\right)\ln ^2x }{1-x^2} \ dx.$$

$$=\frac14\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^4x}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{\frac{93}4\zeta(5)}+\frac{\pi^2}{8}\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{\ln^2x}{1-x^2}\ dx}_{\frac74\zeta(3)}$$

$$=\frac{93}{16}\zeta(5)+\frac{7\pi^2}{32}\zeta(3)$$

$$\Longrightarrow I=\frac{93}{32}\zeta(5)+\frac{7\pi^2}{64}\zeta(3)+\frac{\pi^5}{64}-\frac{\pi}{512}\psi_3(1/4)\tag1$$

---

Now, from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240779/prove-ln1x2-arctan-x-2-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-h-2n2n1x2n1/3373852#3373852) we have

$$\frac{\arctan x}{1+x^2}=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(H_n-2H_{2n}\right)x^{2n-1}$$

which gives

$$\int_0^1\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\ dx=\frac12\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\left(H_n-2H_{2n}\right)\int_0^1 x^{2n-1}\ln^3x\ dx$$

$$=-3\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n-2H_{2n}}{(2n)^4}=-\frac3{16}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^4}+\frac3{8}\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{2n}}{n^4}\tag2$$

By combining $(1)$ and $(2)$ and substituting [$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_n}{n^4}=\frac12\zeta(2)\zeta(3)-\frac{59}{32}\zeta(5)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3449930/how-to-compute-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1nh-nn4-by-real-integration-only) we reach the closed form of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{H_{2n}}{n^4}$.

---

**Explanation for $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty } \frac{ \arctan x\ln ^3x}{1+x^2} \ dx=\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\left(2 \ln ^2x+\pi ^2\right)\ln ^2x }{1-x^2} \ dx$**,

Write $\tan^{-1}x=\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}dy$

$$\Longrightarrow\int_0^{\infty } \frac{ \arctan x\ln ^3x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}dy\right)dx$$

$$=\int_0^1\underbrace{\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{x\ln^3x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2y^2)}dx\right)}_{x^2\mapsto x}dy=\frac1{16}\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{(1+x)(1+y^2x)}dx\right)dy$$

The inner integral was nicely calculated by @Zacky in the comments below and as follows,

$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{(1+x)(1+y^2x)}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{(1+x)(1+y^2x)}dx+\underbrace{\int_1^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{(1+x)(1+y^2x)}dx}_{\large x\mapsto 1/x}$$

$$=\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{(1+x)(1+y^2x)}dx-\int_0^1\frac{\ln^3x}{(1+x)(x+y^2)}dx$$

$$=\frac{1}{16(1-y^2)}\int_0^1 \ln^3 x\left(\frac{2}{1+x}-\frac{1}{y^2+x}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^2}+x}\right)dx$$

$$=-\frac{3}{8(1-y^2)}\left(\color{red}{\frac74\zeta(4)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(-\frac{1}{y^2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(-y^2\right)}\right)$$

Now use the identity

$$\frac74\zeta(4)+\operatorname{Li}_4(1/x)+\operatorname{Li}_4(x)=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}\ln^2(-x)-\frac1{24}\ln^4(-x)$$

replace $x$ with $-y^2$ to get

$$\color{red} {\frac74\zeta(4)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(-\frac{1}{y^2}\right)+\operatorname{Li}_4\left(-y^2\right)}=-\frac{\pi^2}{3}\ln^2y-\frac23\ln^4y$$

giving us

$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{ \arctan x\ln ^3x}{1+x^2} \ dx=\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\left(2 \ln ^2x+\pi ^2\right)\ln ^2x }{1-x^2} \ dx$$

Comment: Write $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\arctan x\ln^3x}{1+x^2}dx,$$ like a double integral. You may use that $$\arctan(x)=\int_0^1 \frac{x}{1+x^2 y^2} \textrm{d}y.$$

Comment: Thus, $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{ \arctan(x)\log ^3(x)}{1+x^2} \textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\left(2 \log ^2(x)+\pi ^2\right)\log ^2(x) }{1-x^2} \textrm{d}x.$$

Comment: (+1) for a good starting point.

Comment: @user97357329 Thank you

Comment: @AliShather do you know why there is
$$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{ \arctan x\ln ^3x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{8} \int_0^1 \frac{\left(2 \ln ^2x+\pi ^2\right)\ln ^2x }{1-x^2}dx?$$

Comment: @Zacky $$\int_0^{\infty } \frac{ \arctan x\ln ^3x}{1+x^2}dx=\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln^3x}{1+x^2}\left(\int_0^1\frac{x}{1+x^2y^2}dy\right)dx$$
$$=\int_0^1\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{x\ln^3x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2y^2)}dx\right)dy$$

For the inner integral, mathematica gives
$$\frac{7\pi^4+8[2\pi^2\ln^2(-iy)+2\pi^2\ln^4(-iy)+2\pi^2\ln^2(iy)+\ln^4(iy)]}{64(1-y^2)}$$


which simplifies to 

$$\frac{1}{8} \frac{\left(2 \ln ^2y+\pi ^2\right)\ln ^2y }{1-y^2}$$

Comment: Well, I for one dislike using mathematica and prefer to have complete solutions. I would start by writing:
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2y^2)}=\frac{1}{1-y^2}\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}-\frac{x}{\frac{1}{y^2}+x^2}\right)$$
$$\int_0^\infty \ln^3 xf(x,y)dx \overset{x^2=t}=\frac1{16(1-y^2)} \int_0^\infty\left( \frac{\ln^3 t}{1+t}-\frac{\ln^3 t}{\frac{1}{y^2}+t}\right)dt$$
Split the integral as $\int_0^1+\int_1^\infty$ and let $t=\frac{1}{x}$ in the second part to get: 
$$=\frac{1}{16(1-y^2)}\int_0^1 \ln^3 x\left(\frac{2}{1+x}-\frac{1}{y^2+x}-\frac{1}{\frac{1}{y^2}+x}\right)dx$$

Comment: The latter integral can be written in terms of quadrilogarithms: $$\frac{3}{8(1-y^2)}\left(2\operatorname{Li}_4\left(-1\right)-\operatorname{Li}_4\left(-\frac{1}{y^2}\right)-\operatorname{Li}_4\left(-y^2\right)\right)$$
And now we might need to use a functional equation from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions). Anyway I don't think all of the above is that easy and shouldn't be left as an exercise to the reader :D But sure, mathematica does it faster.

Comment: @Zacky I agree I didnt know it's that complicated . If I come up with an easy explanation I'll edit my post.

Comment: @AliShather There are more ways to do it. One way is to use the special case of the Beta function, $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{1+t}\textrm{d}t=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)},$$ or $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{t^{x-1}}{1+t^2}\textrm{d}t=\frac{\pi}{2\sin(\pi x/2)}.$$

Comment: @Zacky Now  we can use the identity 

$$\operatorname{Li}_4(x)+\operatorname{Li}_4(1/x)=-\frac74\zeta(4)-\frac12\zeta(2)\ln^2(-x)-\frac1{24}\ln^4(-x)$$

Comment: @Edit profile and settings thank you. so are your /questions/solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Consider
$$\psi \left( -z \right)+\gamma \underset{z\to n}{\mathop{=}}\,\frac{1}{z-n}+{{H}_{n}}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\left( {{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}H_{n}^{k+1}-\zeta \left( k+1 \right) \right){{\left( z-n \right)}^{k}}}, n\ge 0$$
Then
$$\left( \psi \left( -2z \right)+\gamma  \right)\frac{\pi f\left( z \right)}{\sin \left( \pi z \right)}\underset{2z\to 2k+1}{\mathop{=}}\,\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\pi f\left( k+\tfrac{1}{2} \right)}{2\left( z-\tfrac{2k+1}{2} \right)}+O\left( 1 \right)$$
On the other hand we also have
$$\left( \psi \left( -2z \right)+\gamma  \right)\frac{\pi f\left( z \right)}{\sin \left( \pi z \right)}\underset{2z\to 2k}{\mathop{=}}\,\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}f\left( k \right)}{2{{\left( z-k \right)}^{2}}}+\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left\{ {{H}_{2k}}f\left( k \right)+\tfrac{1}{2}f'\left( k \right) \right\}}{z-k}+O\left( 1 \right), k\ge 0$$
Similarly
$$\left( \psi \left( -2z \right)+\gamma  \right)\frac{\pi f\left( z \right)}{\sin \left( \pi z \right)}\underset{z\to -k}{\mathop{=}}\,\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left( \psi \left( 2k \right)+\gamma  \right)f\left( -k \right)}{z+k}, k>0$$
The only other residues are those due to $f$ which we assume has one pole at the origin of order at least $2$.  The sum of residues over the entire plane is zero.  Hence
$$\begin{align}
  & \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{H}_{2k}}f\left( k \right)} \\ 
 & =-\frac{1}{2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}f'\left( k \right)}-\frac{\pi }{2}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty }{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}f\left( k+\tfrac{1}{2} \right)}-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left( \psi \left( 2k \right)+\gamma  \right)f\left( -k \right)}\\&-\underset{z=0}{\mathop{res}}\,\left( \psi \left( -2z \right)+\gamma  \right)\frac{\pi f\left( z \right)}{\sin \left( \pi z \right)} \\ 
\end{align}$$

This goes a long way to generalise such results as you can now pick any power by simply choosing f appropriately.  For example letting $f\left( z \right)=\frac{1}{{{z}^{4}}}$ we find
$$\begin{align}
  & \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{H}_{2k}}}{{{k}^{4}}}} \\ 
 & =-\frac{\pi }{192}\left\{ {{\psi }^{\left( 3 \right)}}\left( \tfrac{1}{4} \right)-{{\psi }^{\left( 3 \right)}}\left( \tfrac{3}{4} \right) \right\}+\frac{2}{3}{{\pi }^{2}}\zeta \left( 3 \right)+\frac{113}{8}\zeta \left( 5 \right)-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\frac{{{H}_{2k-1}}}{{{k}^{4}}}} \\ 
\end{align}$$
Now
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{H}_{2k}}}{{{k}^{4}}}}=A-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{H}_{2k-1}}}{{{k}^{4}}}}\Rightarrow \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left( {{H}_{2k}}+{{H}_{2k-1}} \right)}{{{k}^{4}}}}=A$$
But we can write this as
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}\left( \frac{1}{2k}+2{{H}_{2k-1}} \right)}{{{k}^{4}}}}=A$$
hence
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{H}_{2k-1}}}{{{k}^{4}}}}=\frac{1}{2}A+\frac{15}{64}\zeta \left( 5 \right)$$
We have then
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }{\frac{{{\left( -1 \right)}^{k}}{{H}_{2k}}}{{{k}^{4}}}}=\frac{\pi }{384}\left\{ {{\psi }^{\left( 3 \right)}}\left( \tfrac{3}{4} \right)-{{\psi }^{\left( 3 \right)}}\left( \tfrac{1}{4} \right) \right\}+\frac{{{\pi }^{2}}}{3}\zeta \left( 3 \right)+\frac{437}{64}\zeta \left( 5 \right)$$