# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (\psi(n) - \psi(2n))}{n} = \frac{\pi^2}{16} + \left(\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\right)^2$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

## Show That

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (\psi(n) - \psi(2n))}{n} =\bbox[15px, #B3E0FF, border: 5px groove #0066CC]{\frac{\pi^2}{16} + \left(\frac{\ln(2)}{2}\right)^2}$$

## my work

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n (\psi(n) - \psi(2n))}{n} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \psi(n)}{n} - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \psi(2n)}{n}$$

I denote

$$\omega_1 =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \psi(n)}{n}$$

$$\omega_2 = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \psi(2n)}{n}$$

$$\omega_1= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \psi(n)}{n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \left(\frac{H_{n-1} - \gamma}{n}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{H_{n-1}}{n} - \gamma \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n \frac{1}{n}$$

$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n \left(H_{n} - \frac{1}{n}\right)}{n} + \gamma \log(2) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n H_{n} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \,dx + \gamma \log(2) - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}$$

$$=-\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x(1 + x)} \,dx + \gamma \log(2) + \eta(2) = \gamma \log(2) + \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) - \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x}dx + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1 + x)}{x + 1} dx$$

Comment: You do not say what $\psi(n)$ means, but it appears that you are defining it to be $H_{n-1}-\gamma$, where presumably $\gamma$ is Euler's constant. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, you're correct In this context $\psi(n)$ is defined as $H_{n-1} - \gamma$ where $\gamma$ represents Euler's constant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x} \,\mathrm{d}x}
& = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{k} \int_{0}^{1} {x^{2n+k} \,\mathrm{d}x}} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^{k}}{2n+k+1}} = \sum_{k=2n+1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}}\\
& = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}} - \sum_{k=1}^{2n} {\frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k}} = \ln2 - H_{2n} + H_{n}
\end{aligned}
$$
so
$$
\psi(n)-\psi(2n)=H_{n-1}-H_{2n-1}=H_n-H_{2n}-\frac1{2n}=\int_{0}^{1} {\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x} \,\mathrm{d}x} - \ln2 - \frac1{2n}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\, \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n}(\psi(n)-\psi(2n)) \\
=&\, \int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{n}}\right) \mathrm{d}x-\ln2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{n}}-\frac1{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}\\
=& -\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x + \ln^22 + \frac{\pi^2}{24} = \frac{\pi^2}{16} + \frac{\ln^22}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$
where
$$
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{\pi^2}{48} + \frac{3\ln^22}{4}
$$
**Supplement:** to evaluate the last integral by elementary way, one is to denote
$$
F(a)=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+a^2x^2)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
and
$$
F'(a) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2ax^2}{(1+x)(1+a^2x^2)} \,\mathrm{d}x = -\frac{2\arctan a}{1+a^2} + \frac{2a\ln2}{1+a^2} + \frac{\ln(1+a^2)}{a(1+a^2)}
$$
then antiderivative with $F(0)=0$
$$
\begin{aligned}
F(a)
& = \int_{0}^{a} \left(-\frac{2\arctan u}{1+u^2} + \frac{2u\ln2}{1+u^2} + \frac{\ln(1+u^2)}{u(1+u^2)}\right) \mathrm{d}u \\
& = -(\arctan a)^2 + \ln2 \ln(1+a^2) + \int_{0}^{a} \frac{\ln(1+u^2)}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u - \frac1{4}\ln^2(1+a^2)
\end{aligned}
$$
hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x}\,\mathrm{d}x = F(1)
& = -\frac{\pi^2}{16} + \frac{3\ln^22}{4} + \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+u^2)}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u \\
& = -\frac{\pi^2}{16} + \frac{3\ln^22}{4} + \frac1{2} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln(1+u)}{u} \,\mathrm{d}u \\
& = -\frac{\pi^2}{48} + \frac{3\ln^22}{4}
\end{aligned}
$$
**Supplement 2:** From this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3240779/prove-ln1x2-arctan-x-2-sum-n-1-infty-frac-1n-h-2n2n1x2n1), recalling that
$$
\arctan x \ln (1+x^2) = 2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {\frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_{2n}}{2n+1} x^{2n+1}}
$$
whose derivative gives you
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n}H_{2n}x^{2n}} = -\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^2} - \frac1{2}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}
$$
which can help you finish $\omega_2$ from your approach. Yet lots of the terms will be cancelled by subtraction, there is no need to solve it term by term. Moreover, if we denote
$$
H_{2n} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac1{2n+1} + \frac{H_n}{2}
$$
$$
\frac1{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n}H_{n}x^{2n}} = -\frac1{2}\frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}
$$
you can clearly find
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{x^{2n}}{2n+1}} = -\frac{x\arctan x}{1+x^2}
$$

Comment: @JohnBentin You may see the post like https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2046219/finding-int1-0-frac-ln1xxdx, all the detail you need is in it.